# Angular ng-repeat not showing data from http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's start off with stating the fact that I have looked in if not all, most of the questions regarding this problem, but unfortunately I could not find an answer to this.

I have this basic http.get:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp' ,[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
  $http.get("http://source.php")
  .then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.results = response.data.records;
  });
});
```

This gets data out from a php file, there it is encoded to JSON, and it looks like this:

```
{ "records":[
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"somedata"},
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"somedata"}
]}
```

BTW: I have checked the whole JSON result through a JSON validator so there is nothing wrong with it.

The data is "printed" in the HTML like so:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in results">
    <td>{{item.itemnumber}}</td>
    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    <td>{{item.something}}</td>
</tr>
```

The thing is that it does not populate the table.

HOWEVER

If I go to the scope and instead of `response.data.records` I paste the results manually it does populate the table.

```
$scope.results = [
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"something"},
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"something"}
];
```

Tracking by `track by $index` is not helping.

Angular tags are bound like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" >

<div class="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in results">
        <td>{{item.itemnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.something}}
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I am sure is something I am overlooking, I just can't figure out what that is.

@edit

@ImmanuelKirubaharan, thanks, you asking me this lead to to find the issue. Somehow I edited the source.php and I have added some  tags there which caused the issue. Thank you ! 
If you would like to post your comment inside an answer I will gladly select it.

Comment: What is your response to this URL "http:// source.php" ?

Comment: The response is exactly like so:
In the PHP file I echo a var which prints this
{ "records":[
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"somedata"},
{"itemnumber":"number","description":"item description","something":"somedata"}
]}

Comment: use `<pre>{{ results | json }}</pre>` to see what your list look like, and debug with that

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharan, thanks, you asking me this lead to to find the issue.
Somehow I edited the source.php and I have added some <html> tags there which caused the issue. Thank you !

Comment: Yeah! Great.. I found no issue in your code.. things are seems to be perfectly working fine which I've tried it with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FBVBxIXDerZbygIBlKaQ?p=preview)..